# split a range of numbers into several ranges with ranges-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have a certain amount of points and some tetrahedra in space and, for each point, I compute in which tetrahedron it is. Point that are not in a tetrahedron are discarded.

```
auto samplerIdAndCoarseTetra = mcSamplers 
    ranges::views::transform([&coarseAABBTree](const auto &mcSampler) {
        return coarseAABBTree.any_intersected_primitive(mcSampler);
    }) |
    ranges::views::enumerate | ranges::views::filter([](const auto &tetrahedron) -> bool {
        return std::get<1>(tetrahedron).has_value();
    }) |
    ranges::views::transform([&coarseResCGALTetrahedra](const auto &tetrahedron) {
        return std::make_tuple(
           std::get<0>(tetrahedron),
           std::distance(std::begin(coarseResCGALTetrahedra), std::get<1>(tetrahedron).value()));
    });
```

Now I have a ranges of a tuple of ints (one for the index of the point, one for the index of the tetrahedron). One possible result is something like this:

```
({0,4}, {1,4}, {3, 2}, {4,4},{4,2})
```

Now I want to separate the points in the tetrahedron number 4 from the points in the tetrahedron number 2. I can order the tuples so I have

```
({0,4}, {1,4}, {4, 4}, {3,2},{4,2})
```

but I still to separate this range into 2 ranges

```
({0,4}, {1,4}, {4,4}), ({4,4}, {4,2})
```

is it possible to achieve this using only ranges-v3? I know there is a `ranges::views::split`, but this splits on a value, and this case looks different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `split`, but `group_by`:

```
auto same_tetra = [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs){ return std::get<1>(lhs) == std::get<1>(rhs); };
// vec, your range of tuples.
auto groups = vec | ranges::view::group_by(same_tetra);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42efff5307613cb5)